# Update single table multiple times in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called test with below data
[image]

data in the table was transnational data. On 2017-04-01 we had units, and again next transaction was made on 2017-04-05 with units 7.

Now i want to update the Units column for all the missing transaction dates with that of the last transaction date.

like : on 2017-04-02 , 2017-04-03 , 2017-04-04 units should be 5
 on 2017-04-06 , 2017-04-07, 2017-04-08, 2017-04-09 units should be 7.

I tried using merge statement in sql , but was unsuccessful. little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried (it doesn't matter that it did not work)?  One technique you could use is [a self-join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL:

```
UPDATE TEST 
   SET UNITS = (SELECT TOP 1 UNITS 
                      FROM TEST t1 
                     WHERE t1.TDATE < TEST.TDATE 
                       AND t1.UNITS IS NOT NULL
                     ORDER BY TDATE DESC)
 WHERE UNITS IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try below update statement it work for me with given data.

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table
(
    col1 INT,
    tdate date,
    units INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-01',5)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-02',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-03',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-04',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-05',7)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-06',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-07',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-08',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-09',NULL)

DECLARE @i int=0;

UPDATE @tblTest SET @i=units=0+ISNULL(units,@i)

SELECT * FROM @tblTest
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and easy solution I use all the time. More information on [simple-talk.com](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/filling-in-missing-values-using-the-t-sql-window-frame/).

```
DECLARE
    @Units int;

UPDATE Test
    SET
        @Units = Units = CASE WHEN Units IS NULL THEN @Units ELSE Units END
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE`  FUNCTION WE CAN USE FOR THIS SCENARIO

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table
    (
        col1 INT,
        tdate date,
        units INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-01',5)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-02',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-03',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-04',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-05',7)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-06',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-07',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-08',NULL)
    INSERT INTO @tblTest values (12344,'2017-04-09',NULL)

    DECLARE @i int=0;

    UPDATE @tblTest SET @i=units=0+COALESCE(units,@i)

    SELECT * FROM @tblTest
```

OUTPUT

```
col1    tdate   units
12344   2017-04-01  5
12344   2017-04-02  5
12344   2017-04-03  5
12344   2017-04-04  5
12344   2017-04-05  7
12344   2017-04-06  7
12344   2017-04-07  7
12344   2017-04-08  7
12344   2017-04-09  7
```